# US Credit Building strategy: Have both an Unsecured and a Secured Credit Card?

Tags: credit-history, credit-cards

I'm about to immigrate under EB3 visa (employment-based green card), and I'm applying for some unsecured credit cards ([CreditStacks](http://creditstacks.com), [Advancial](http://advancial.org), and [American Express Global Card Transfers](https://www.americanexpress.com/global-card-transfers/) - but I also accept other suggestions if any).

I read [here](https://www.creditcards.com/credit-card-news/fico-score-type-credit-loan-mix-1270.php) that a good diversity (credit mix) will help improve my score.

Assuming that I can get one unsecured card, **does it still make sense to also get a secured card**?

Will it help my credit-score if I get 2 unsecured cards?

Additionally, for getting a good mortgage rate in the future, **should my spouse also worry about building her own credit score**?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to credit cards in the US. Some US banks are notorious for making it tricky to pay on time, which allows them to charge high fees, and also harms your credit rating. Credit unions are owned by their members and have a good reputation for low fees and convenient policies. You're new employer may have its own; otherwise there will be credit unions in the community. See https://www.ncua.gov

Comment: Good Lord!  I can't remember when I last had a credit card that *didn't* have a direct debit associated with it to pay the credit card in full every month.  (It is thus the bank's responsibility to take the money on time).  20 years ago? (Cards in GB, DE, CH)

Comment: @MartinBonner: What you're describing sounds more like a [charge card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_card), rather than a credit card. A credit card is is tied to a revolving line of credit.

Comment: @GregHewgill What MartinBonner is describing is very much a credit card, just paid off in full every month.  I do the same with my UK credit card.